# Converting Google Maps API to DOJO/ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps-api, dojo, arcgis-online-basemaps, html5

I have a GIS webpage in HTML5/JavaScript using the Google Maps API. I found out we can no longer use the Google Maps imagery provided, and I need to switch to ESRI Imagery (free).

Can someone help me is how I go about this?

As I understand the ESRI stuff uses DOJO and since I am already using JavaScript can I simply change some of my code to work?

I have a map with a few markers, lines and a circle polygon (around the marker) nothing too crazy.

Comment: The [ArcGIS API for JavaScript pages](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) may be a good place to start, as well as Q&As here tagged [tag:arcgis-javascript-api] and/or [tag:arcgis-online] (I'm assuming the latter is the Esri Imagery you mention).

Comment: Follow this link for how to add esri imagery using dojo, https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html